# How to start a reverse tunnel with PuTTY?

Tags: ssh-tunnel, putty

I am trying to make a tunnel between a server and laptop with Putty. The problem is, since the laptop has no public IP address, I have to make a reverse connection.

ASCII Artwork:

```
SERVER(PORT:6000) ----------> LAPTOP(PORT:7000)
```

However, since laptop has no public IP Address I have to:

```
SERVER(PORT:6000) <---------- LAPTOP(PORT:7000)
```

But, all the data coming from will be transferred from server to laptop.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In PuTTY go to Settings -> Connection -> SSH -> Tunnels. You can add port forwards there. For reverse forward, enter source port, and destination, but choose 'Remote' instead of 'Local'.

In your case, put 6000 in to source port, localhost:7000 in the Destination, and choose Remote.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying the same but I still can not connect :( What can be the problem ??

Comment: How did you try?

Comment: Don't forget to check the two checkboxes : 'Local ports accept connections from other hosts' and 'Remote ports do the same'

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the -R option to ssh.  It allows you to establish a connection backwards (well both ways).  See [this page](http://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling) for more

Comment: Thanks but I want to do it with putty, is there anyway to do it with putty ??

Comment: Yes.  The SSH Tunnels page allows you to set it up.  The Help link should describe it.  otherwise, use plink from the command-line